# html select control click not showing options list until mouse is hovered towards the options

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am facing a strange problem with select-tag, that I have a simple select drop down and when I click on it, the options list does not show up until I move the mouse in the direction where the options list might have shown(if worked properly). That is if the space is available above the select then after clicking the drop down the options are not showing until I move the mouse in the upward direction. And if the space is available below the select then after clicking the drop down the options are not showing until I move the mouse in the downward direction.

This problem happens only in IE9. FireFox, Chrome work properly.

Background: my application url is opened inside an iframe as the application is used within a workspace app.

Comment: Why don't you put some code.

Comment: As I said it is simple select-tag within a workspace app of which I dont have much knowledge. In the debugger I could only find that it is used inside iframe. Hence if I open my app url directly with out the workspace app the problem does not show up